# How do I tell which javascript framework is validating forms on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, prototype

I am trying to build a chrome extension to enter data into online forms on sites like toysrus.com and macys.com.  A chrome extension can inject javascript into the site to do tests. I am trying to determine which framework is being used to do form validation on the site.

I have to change the input fields like choose "CA" for the State, or type in a last name using javascript. But I can't do that if I don't know what system they are using. Each framework has it's own rules for changing an input field and having the change register with the framework.

I'm trying to see if there's any way to tell which framework is doing the validation, so I can use the right commands.

In the case of toysrus.com prototype.js and jquery were both running as detected by whether the variable jQuery or Prototype existed,
but I had to use prototype syntax to get and change a value in a form and not jquery. I had to do this through much trial and error manually.

Is there any javascript I can write and inject into the page to tell which framework's is being used to validate a form on these sites.

I noticed that in the case above $("#elementid") returned null, but $("elementid") returned an actual element. That told me that Prototype was doing the actual validation. Are there any tests or perhaps a js library that can determine what framework is being used on an element?

Comment: as developer, you MUST know on which page, which libs has been load, then you check if the libs undefined or not

Comment: use vanilla js...problem solved

Comment: @charlietfl ,yep, vanilla js is good, it's tiny, only 25 bytes, and much popular than angular, jquery...

Comment: This is for a chrome extension changing fields on pre-existing webpages such as toysrus.com, and macys.com, so I have to work with whatever they have on the page.

Comment: @techdog, then there is no guarantee solution, but the conflict between prototype and jquery is obvious

Comment: I updated the question, because the first one was confusing. It made it sound like I had control over the website or could choose which framework to use.

Comment: What is your definition of "validating forms"?  What EXACTLY are you looking for?

Comment: I have to change the input fields like choose CA for the State, or type in a last name using javascript.  But I can't do that if I don't know what system they are using. Each framework has it's own rules for changing an input field and having the change register with the framework. I'm trying to see if there's any way to tell which framework is doing the validation, so I can use the right commands.

Comment: Please describe this in your question (use the edit feature to add it). Questions here need to describe the ***ACTUAL problem*** you are trying to solve, not just your current attempt at a solution. Only now do we actually understand what you're really trying to do and this needs to be IN your question, not just in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

mate , to you specific case, your prototype and jquery are conflicting with the dollar sign,

just do this :

```
<!-- Another way to put jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
$( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable in the global scope has the prototype.js meaning.
window.onload = function(){
  var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

`

update:
mate, there is gonna be no guarantee solution if you insist using frameworks, only possible way is using pure javascript, that vanilla js!

Comment: @techdog, mate, there is gonna be no guarantee  solution if you insist using frameworks, only possible way is using pure javascript, that vanilla js!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I was unclear in my original post. I don't have any control over what frameworks another site uses. I'm trying to detect which frameworks the site uses for form validation. I edited the original post because it was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, unless you have complicated things to do that require a framework, it might be easiest to just use `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` and use plain Javascript and not worry about a framework.

If you really want to determine which framework is present, then you can develop a feature test for each framework and test them in the order that you care about.

For example:

```
if (typeof jQuery !== "undefined") {
    // jQuery present
} else if (typeof angular !== "undefined") {
    // angular present
} else if (typeof Prototype !== "undefined") {
    // Prototype present
} else if (typeof dojo !== "undefined") {
    // dojo present
} else {
    // don't see any framework
}
```

Depending upon exactly what you're trying to do, there are more comprehensive tests possible too for each framework.

FYI, when using jQuery in an unfamiliar page, I would suggest using `jQuery` as your root identifier and not `$` as in `jQuery(...)`, not `$(...)`.  This will prevent getting confused if some other framework is using `$`.

Comment: he opened a new ticket here,, sigh..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226777/how-would-i-use-javascript-to-identify-which-javascript-frameworks-are-being-use  , properly, he won't give you the TICK...

Comment: I closed the other question and am trying again here. The original was confusing and made it sound like I could choose the framework. This is a chrome extension that "looks" at existing websites and fills in forms on sites like toysrus,macys, etc.

Comment: @techdog - then I guess I'll delete my answer in a while because you've now changed the question to something else which my answer does not cover.